# Is there a mininimum font size setting for Anti-Aliasing for Java apps like Android Studio

Tags: ubuntu, java, fonts, eclipse, intellij-idea

When I try to use choose a font for the editor in Android Studio, it doesn't apply Anti-Aliasing on fonts for smaller sizes. 
With the Ubuntu Mono font Anti-Aliasing only appears after size 20, other fonts it happens at 16. But on Eclipse anti-aliasing works on even at size 12. 
So you end up having to use large fonts on Android Studio, which means you see less visible code. If you choose a smaller font, there is no Anti-Aliasing and my eyes become strained. I know Android Studio is based on IntelliJ's Idea.

Currently I am using these settings in the studio64.vmoptions settings file

```
-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=lcd
-Dswing.aatext=true
-Dsun.java2d.xrender=true
```

I have tried various settings for Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings and still the same issue.
Is there another setting to control at which size Anti-Aliasing is turned on.

Here are some screenshots Ubuntu Mono 16 (No Anti-Aliasing) :

[image: Ubuntu Mono 16]

Ubuntu Mono 20 (has Anti-Aliasing)
[image: Ubuntu Mono 20]

Ubuntu Mono 12 in **Eclipse** (ideal for me) 
[image: Ubuntu Mono 12]

I have uploaded [the images to imgur as this site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYcIv.jpg) is compressing the images, and the quality is affected.

I am using Android Studio 0.86, Oracle's Java 7 on Ubuntu 12.04 with Nvidia drivers.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/614960/how-to-fix-font-anti-aliasing-in-intellij-idea-when-using-high-dpi ?

Comment: Rsya no that's deal with using openJDK, I am using Oracle's I have tried editing the glyphs but that had no effect

Comment: In the answer doesn't it tell you to use Oracle JDK instead of OpenJDK?

Comment: Your first screenshot **does** have antialiasing, it's just the very bad one you get with OpenJDK and (to a way lesser extent) with Oracle JDK. You should consider using OpenJDK with the *font fix* applied.