# How to correct IdeaJ IDE on Win7 font setting bugs? Or just the fonts bug itself?

Tags: windows-7, fonts, sublime-text-2, intellij-idea

I try to use `fixedsys` for IDEA IDE which downloaded from http://www.fixedsysexcelsior.com/

Set the font size to 16 and then the `A` and `B` character just overlapped each other.

other size will be fine but It shows not perfect.

### with size = 16

[image: bug_pic]
'A' character in render result takes no space and will be overlapped by the character follow after 'A'.

`Notepad` or `sublime` use the same font same size shows just correct.

### with size != 16

[image: bug_pic2]

if it is the bug of the font, how do I fix the font by myself?

if it is the IDEA bug or java bug, how to walk around with it?

Answer (score 0):

According to this [Superuser Answer](https://superuser.com/a/623596/201422), I tried add one option to idea.vmoptions:

```
-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on
```

It now works correct, solved the problem, but the cause of the problem is still unknown, JRE Bug? AWT bug? IDEA bug?

IDEA still shows wrong with some gui part, but code part works when using the font